# error MSB4057: The target "GetProjectOutputPa th" does not exist in the project

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to build a solution out of the custom controller using power apps components framework:

Using

- Microsoft PowerApps Cli
- .net framework 4.6.2 development pack
- .Net SDK 2.2 Core
- Visual Studio code
- Node.js

I used [this link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/bitsandbytesbydanish/archive/2019/05/18/create-custom-controls-using-powerapp-component-framework) as a guidenence

However, I am getting this error:

> "MSB4057: The target "GetProjectOutputPath" does not exist in the project"

after executing msbuild in the desired location and no zipped solution is created..? Why?

I want to consume it in the D365 later.

Answer (score 1):

PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerApps.MSBuild.Solution" Version="0.1.34" added to cdproj file solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer helped: https://imgur.com/aPjEdcW

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added node project (`.njsproj`) to be part of the `.cdsproj` and it was failing the same as for you. So, I added a missing target to `.njsproj`:

```
<Target Name="GetProjectOutputPath" />
```

That have solved issue for me. If you would go to targets of the pcf nugget you will see how exactly `GetProjectOutputPath` is used.